# flask-sqlalchemy with dynamic database connections

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have one main db, in which each client's own db connection is stored. 
So every client works with 2 db: main and its own db, connection of which must be decided 
for each http call. How can I do this using flask-sqlalchemy extension, or may be 
purely in sqlalchemy?

Comment: Are these two databases sharing the same data?

Answer (score 7):

You can handle multiple sessions in Flask-SQLalchemy:

```
engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URI)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                     autoflush=False,
                                     bind=engine))
db_session.query...()
```

and

```
engine2 = create_engine(DATABASE_URI2)
db_session2 = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                     autoflush=False,
                                     bind=engine2))

db_session2.query2...()
```

sharing the same codebase.

Comment: this code does not reflect how it would be done with Flask-SQLAlchemy, but rather specifically with SQLAlchemy directly.

Comment: Right, the code is only for plain SQLAlchemy, but question was not specific about using Flask-SQLAlchemy. Making it work with the wrapper should be easy, anyway. Also, you also can use both in the same codebase.